# Horizontal Align labels

Tags: swift

How can i generate a random amount of labels and align them next to each other in the middle?

I have this code to generate an label:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 196, 35,45 ))
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.text = "1";
    label.tag = 5;
    self.view.addSubview(label);
```

This work perfect, but how can i generate more than 1 label and set them next to each other in the middle?

like this:

[image]

Or if i generate 3 labels it must looks like this:
[image]

Is this possible to do it programmaticly?

Comment: You can use auto layout.

Comment: @BensonTommy Programmaticly?

Comment: You can add a container view which is center horizontally,and programmatically add those labels into this container view.

Comment: Don't walk away from a previously asked question and ask it again. _Fix_ the previously asked question.

Comment: Just use simple math...

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var lastLabel : UILabel?
var count = 1

@IBAction func addlabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.text = count.description;
    count++
    label.tag = 5;


    var centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    centerX.priority = 999
    //This if you want to center it vertically also
    var centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 35)
    var width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 45)

    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(label);

    if let prevlabel = lastLabel {
        var align = NSLayoutConstraint(item: prevlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        //Here just add the NSLayoutConstraint you want to apply, if its only horizontal then not add  centerY

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([align, centerY, height, width, centerX])
    }else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([centerX, centerY, height, width])
    }
    lastLabel = label
}
```

Comment: Wont this just add every label to the same spot and not spread them out?

Comment: yes yes, i'm seeing that right now, i'm testing it to update my answer